Unverified GitHub commits, using gpg keys on yubikey
I set up a set of GPG keys on my Yubikey to use for git signing. I followed a guide that is, unfortunately, behind a paywall, so I won't link it. (I'll be abbreviating keys in this post to just a few letters)
After setting everything up with gpg and git, my commits were signing just fine:
This commit was signed with the committer's verified signature.
GPG Key ID: BE4

A little while later I was signing a commit and it showed up as unverified with a different key ID on GitHub:
The signature in this commit could not be verified. Someone may be trying to trick you.
GPG Key ID: 6D8

This 6D8 key is one of the subkeys:
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
[keyboxd]
---------
sec#  ed25519/BE4 2024-04-08 [SC]
      <long format>BE4
uid                 [ultimate] My Name (master key) <me@mydomain.com>
ssb>  cv25519/752 2024-04-08 [E]
ssb>  ed25519/38F 2024-04-08 [SA]
ssb>  ed25519/6D8 2024-04-08 [S]

It is listed as such on GitHub as well:
Key ID: BE4
Subkeys: 752 , 38F , 6D8

Eventually, I figured out that adding a bang (!) to my key in my gitconfig would force it to use the BE4 key, and my commits showed up as verified again:
user.signingkey=BE4!

This commit was signed with the committer's verified signature.
GPG Key ID: BE4

Yesterday, I was trying to sign a commit and got the following error:
❯ git commit -m "added new dependencies"
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED BE4 0
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H10
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 67108881
gpg: signing failed: No secret key

fatal: failed to write commit object

I figured out it would work again if I removed the bang (!) from the key in my gitconfig:
user.signingkey=BE4

But now my git commits show up as unverified on GitHub again:
The signature in this commit could not be verified. Someone may be trying to trick you.
GPG Key ID: 1AD1C403D903C6D8

How do I make sure my commits are signed properly and show up as verified on GitHub with this setup?
